# 54 Games Missing From Steam Library

Tags: steam, technical-issues

Since Steam forced its new "improved" UI on its users, 54 games have vanished from my library—and that's just ONE Steam account; two others are similarly afflicted. All owned games show up in Games Owned in user profile, but one cannot MANAGE the games (install or launch, et cetera) from there.

Shortly before this new undesired and disastrous change in the UI, I had reset my Steam Library preferences to default, removing all category settings. Now the old settings are back, and it's a hopeless mess.

Answer (score 10):

### In all probability a specific filter is set in the new UI, preventing you from seeing all games.

There are several ways this can be changed:

1. Maybe the dedicated button to filter out games that are currently unavailable is switched on:

   [image: Steam - Show only Read to Play games]
2. There is a myriad of preset tags to choose from to filter your game library to create '*Dynamic Collections*', and this might have filtered out part of your library:

   [image: Steam - Set up Dynamic Collections]
3. Lastly, there is a drop-down menu to the left of the former two options, that allows you to filter software, videos, and tools. The option for 'Games' might be deselected:

   [image: Steam - Filter media]

Answer (score 3):

I found for me that the "missing games" weren't actually games.  I have my library set up into 2 Collections: Favorites and Uncategorized.  You can see that there is a lot missing from Uncategorized:

[image: Steam library missing games]

Similar to the answer from  @Joachim, if you go into the filter settings and select Unplayed, a new category called "Tools" will appear.  Here I see a bunch of dedicated servers for games I've never installed, as well as a few SDK's and other things.

[image: Steam library filter]

Answer (score -1):

For Steam users who have multiple Steam accounts: while you SHOULD be able to catalog games by account and see the categories accurately delineate ownership... *the interface does not always **behave** the same from account to account*.

The easiest way to avoid the issue is to be proactive, immediately move just-purchased games from Uncategorized to the appropriate category.

When you don't avoid the problem, when you initiate game installation you will be notified that you are borrowing—assuming you have granted library sharing rights across all of your accounts—such-and-such a game from such-and-such an account—when installation is attempted from an account other than that of the owner.

Answer (score -3):

I found the most satisfactory solution possible by experimentation:

At first, I was unable to modify or edit the categories and the items within them, because the new system works differently from the old system. The total number of games in all owned accounts are *somewhat* accurately tracked (*accurate for currently logged-in account, not so much for the others*).

Uninstalling Steam and cleaning the registry doesn't work; undesired settings are restored from the cloud upon reinstallation. The best I could do was delete all but the uncategorized groupings and/or the items within them [via context menu] (*deleting all the items in a category removes that category*).

I've been a Steam member since 2007 and a computer user since 1984. I had to make handwritten lists of owned games in the accounts' profiles and compare them to all the uncategorized  games (*a **must**!*) before I could determine whether or not any were indeed missing. This was a process requiring many **hours** of boringly repetitive work, which I would not have had to perform otherwise (So thank you, Steam, for making this *SO* accursedly confusing).

Comment: I can't tell what the solution was for you. Could you clean up your answer to be less of a rant and more of an explanation?

Comment: Hi William, I've shortened your answer somewhat to focus more on the solution you found, rather than the rant/threat of boycotting, as I believe the info you've provided will help others in similar situations. As a longtime Steam user myself I understand your frustration with the new categorization system, but ranting at us isn't going to change it, we're not Valve, just frustrated users like yourself.

Comment: What was the underlying problem? Your answer makes it sounds as if your categories were indeed jumbled.